# Prompt to choose launcher isnt showing once or always options

Tags: android

I am trying to show the prompt that asks users to choose a launcher but the option to select "once" or "always" isnt showing. How can I display these options?

```
Intent selector = new Intent();
selector.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
selector.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(selector, "Select Launcher"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing is in the system's default chooser. Because you're specifically asking for a chooser, you can't set the system's default. If you want that experience, you have to prompt to start an activity without a chooser, and allow the OS to handle it. If a default application hasn't been chosen, the chooser you're referencing will show up. If a default has been chosen, it will open the default without a chooser.

Comment: So there is no way to make it always prompt to choose a default app? I have a kiosk browser app that always shows the system prompt to choose a launcher

Comment: Well, that's the point of the "set as default" behavior. Once the default is set, it won't show anymore.